# org-mode export with ox-pandoc: setting CSS for HTML5 output

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

The latest versions of emacs and ox-pandoc already provide a great output but I need to customize the HTML5 output by setting a CSS stylesheet that matches my company's templates.

How can I do that?

I tried adding:

```
#+PANDOC_OPTIONS: css: ./style.css
```

and even

```
#+PANDOC_OPTIONS: css: <style>h1, h2 {color: #00abff;}; </style>
```

but I get this:

```
org-babel-exp process bash at position 3277...
Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

This would make producing reports so much easier than using word documents and slides and such manually.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about `ox-pandoc` (which seems to be an external package - maybe you can add a URL for it?) but maybe you need to quote the CSS: ` #+PANDOC_OPTIONS: css: "<style>h1, h2 {color: #00abff;}; </style>"`. Here's [an example of setting CSS with the standard HTML exporter](https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#CSS-support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the style in an HTML block:

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
<style>
h1, h2 {
  color: #00abff;
}
</style>
#+END_HTML
```